# Can't import module of pod that has been installed?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have installed pod of `SlideMenuController`. I have followed the [steps](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) specified. But still getting error

> No such module 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'

Actually when I checked this error, I found a lot of different suggestions. I really want to know what is the exact problem even after following the required steps.

Comment: Which Xcode you are using?

Comment: Build, first, before importing a pod.

Comment: @Dharmesh  I am using Xcode 9.0.

Comment: You should use latest one now.

Comment: @Dharmesh Is there any issue regarding the version of Xcode ??

Comment: It may be. Can you try remove import and check?

Comment: @Dharmesh. I had tried a suggestion by Harish ie. adding library in Project > General. when I tried like u z got error "ld: framework not found SlideMenuControllerSwift
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @Dharmesh I removed the library "SlideMenuControllerSwift" , now it is successfully built

Comment: I didn't told you to remove library just remove `import SlideMenuControllerSwift`

Comment: @Dharmesh Yes u r correct. I just reverted the step that's all. After removing the import statement it is successfully built

Comment: check if you can access it's methods?

Comment: @Dharmesh Nope :(

Comment: Can you share demo project so that I can check it on my side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190889/discussion-between-karan-alangat-and-dharmesh).

Comment: @Dharmesh let me try

Comment: @Dharmesh Thanks a lot for your support and time. I fixed it by myself. The issue was i was specifying the pod name in side the nested target block ie. "target 'projnameTests' do" in the pod file. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out this with below steps

1. Kindly clean your derived data and run again.
2. Clean your project and run again.
3. Re-Open your .XCWorkspace and run (Make sure that after installing a pod through cocoapods you need to stop using the xcode project and switch over to the workspace created by cocoapods.)
4. Add frameworks SlideMenuControllerSwift from general

[image]

**Note**: If you are using the latest XCode 10.2 then your pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift' should support swift 4/ 4.2/5 Language as your latest Xcode 10.2 doesn't support swift 3. Check which language 'SlideMenuControllerSwift' using.

Comment: If it works you can give one thump Up to my answer.

Comment: I have tried 4 steps, but still the issue remains. I am trying to set the search path

Answer (score 0):

Best way to resolve this issue is follow these steps

1) click on project or in product in xcode then click on manage scheme

2) after uncheck your project and check your pod u have installed

3) Build your application with your pod

4) After again change your scheme and uncheck pod and check your app this will works , i added images to explain this :)

[image: First Step[![][1]]][Second Step[[image: ]]][third step and build app]